# Why this for loop over the matrix changing values incorrectly?

Tags: python, matrix

The task at hand is to detect zeros in a matrix and set all cells in the same row, column to zeros.
E.g. given matrix with 0

```
[ 1 2 0]
[ 4 5 7]
[ 9 8 3]
```

becomes

```
[ 0 0 0]
[ 4 5 0]
[ 9 8 0]
```

I tried to solve similar problem, created helper 'mark_matrix' with all 1 and set it to zero whenever i find 0 in the original matrix.

Here is the [online ide code](https://replit.com/join/qtfwcfhlud-erjang) to run it. I included lots of print statements, the logic: whenever zero found, it takes current [i,j] and starts going thru the helper mark_matrix to set the i-th row and j-th column to zeros.

```
class Sol:
    def print_matrix(self, m):
        for i in range(0, len(m)):
            for j in range(0, len(m[0])):
                print(m[i][j], sep=' ', end=' ')
            print()
        print('------')

    def fill_row_column_zeros(self, m):

        mark_matrix = [1]*len(m[0])
        mark_matrix = [mark_matrix] * len(m)
        print('before, empty mark matrix')
        self.print_matrix(mark_matrix)

        for i in range(len(m)):
            for j in range(len(m[0])):
                if m[i][j] != 0:
                    print('skipping [%d][%d] ' % (i, j))

                elif m[i][j] == 0:
                    print('found zero at [%d][%d] ' % (i, j))

                    print('-----------------------')

                    row = i
                    column = j

                    for a in range(len(m)):
                        for b in range(len(m[0])):
                            print('row is %d' % row)
                            if a == row:
                                mark_matrix[a][b] = 0
                                print(
                                    'changing at coords:  [%d][%d]' % (row, b))
                        self.print_matrix(mark_matrix)

                    for a in range(len(m)):
                        for b in range(len(m[0])):
                            print('columns is %d' % column)
                            if b == column:
                                mark_matrix[a][b] = 0
                                print(
                                    'changing at coords:  [%d][%d]' % (b, column))

                        self.print_matrix(mark_matrix)

        print('\n')
        print('***** END *******')
        print('mark matrix now')
        self.print_matrix(mark_matrix)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Sol()

    m = [[1, 3, 0], [4, 5, 6], [6, 8, 9]]
    print('original matrix')

    s.fill_row_column_zeros(m)
```

However it just changes the entire helper mark_matrix to zeros. I did check the indexes.

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

e.g. the zero is at [0,2] so I take all the row's indices - [0,0], [0,1],[0,2] and set to 0
Same for j=2, [0,2], [1,2],[2,2] set to 0. But the matrix becomes all 0

```
 [ 1 2 0]
 [ 4 5 7]
 [ 9 8 3]
```

Comment: is there a book where i can read about these subtleties of python?

Comment: I’m pretty sure it’s mentioned in the relevant part of the Python documentation. You can pretty much find all the common pit falls by perusing the FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?tab=Frequent

Comment: See Note 2 here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations